# Rendering a laser beam - how to make it face camera?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

(I am using a LibGDX framework which is basically just LWJGL(Java) with OpenGL for rendering) 
Hi, I'm trying to render a laser beam, so far I've got this effect, [image: laser beam]

It's just a rectangle and then the whole effect is done in fragment Shader.

However, as it is a laser beam, I want the rectangle to face a camera, so the player always sees this red transparent "line" everytime. And this is driving me crazy. I tried to do some billboarding stuff, however what I want isn't really billboarding. I just want to rotate it on Z axis so that the player always sees the whole line, that's all. No X and Y rotations.

[image]

As you can see, that's what I want. And it's not billboarding at all.

If it was billboarding, it would look like this: [image] .

I also tried to draw cylinder and the effect based on gl_FragCoord, which was working fine, but the coords were varying(sometimes the UVs were 0 and 1, sometimes 0 and 0.7) and it was not sampling whole texture, so the effect was broken.

Thus I don't even know what to do now.
I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Here's vertexShader code:

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans; //model matrix
uniform mat4 u_view; //view matrix
uniform mat4 u_proj; // projection matrix

varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

void main() {
    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;

    vec4 worldTrans = u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);

    gl_Position = u_proj * u_view * worldTrans; 
}
```

and here's fragmentShader codE:

```
#ifdef GL_ES 
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

uniform sampler2D tex; //texture I apply the red color onto. It's how I get the smooth(transparent) edges. 

void main() {
vec4 texelColor = texture2D( tex, v_texCoord0 ); //sampling the texture
vec4 color = vec4(10.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); //the red color

float r = 0.15; //here I want to make the whole texture be red, so when there's less transparency, I want it to be more red, and on the edges(more transparency) less red.
if (texelColor.a > 0.5) r = 0.1;

gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color.rgb,texelColor.rgb,texelColor.a * r),texelColor.a); //and here I just mix the two colors into one, depengind on the alpha value of texColor and the r float.
    }
```

The texture is just a white line opaque in the middle, but transparent at the edges of the texuture. (smooth transition)

Comment: Please post your shader code.

Comment: What does it look like when failing to do what you want? do you have another image representing the problem besides the billboarding example.

Comment: When I do billboarding, it always faces the camera, which isn't quite what I want. Imagine a building where each laser has its position(starts somewhere and endes somewhere, has its direction). I don't want it to to face camera, because in that case its direction would change depending on camera's position.. I want the laser to face the camera only on Z axis (so that the camera always sees the red line, but the laser wouldn't face the camera at all.

Comment: I've done this using DecalBatch. What means are you using to draw the line? Are you drawing a Mesh directly? This is called axial billboarding, as opposed to the spherical billboarding you were talking about.

Comment: It's just a rectangle model created by ModelBuilder, and then I pass that model to a ModelInstance. So I am drawing a modelInstance. Anyway, I also tried to use the decalBatch but it was just the same - it was facing the camera on all axis. About the axial billboarding - I haven't found a lot about it on internet, but it seems to be the thing I'm after. Is it possible to achieve the axial billboarding with libGDX's decal implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use DecalBatch to draw your laser, you can do it this way. It's called axial billboarding or cylindrical billboarding, as opposed to the spherical billboarding you described.

The basic idea is that you calculate the direction the sprite would be oriented  for spherical billboarding, and then you do a couple of cross products to get the component of that direction that is perpendicular to the axis.

Let's assume your laser sprite is aligned to point up and down. You would do this series of calculations on every frame that the camera or laser moves.

```
//reusable calculation vectors
final Vector3 axis = new Vector3();
final Vector3 look = new Vector3();
final Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();

void orientLaserDecal (Decal decal, float beamWidth, Vector3 endA, Vector3 endB, Camera camera) {
    axis.set(endB).sub(endA); //the axis direction

    decal.setDimensions(beamWidth, axis.len());

    axis.scl(0.5f);
    tmp.set(endA).add(axis); //the center point of the laser

    decal.setPosition(tmp);

    look.set(camera.position).sub(tmp); //Laser center to camera. This is
        //the look vector you'd use if doing spherical billboarding, so it needs 
        //to be adjusted.
    tmp.set(axis).crs(look); //Axis cross look gives you the 
        //right vector, the direction the right edge of the sprite should be 
        //pointing. This is the same for spherical or cylindrical billboarding.
    look.set(tmp).crs(axis); //Right cross axis gives you an adjusted
        //look vector that is perpendicular to the axis, i.e. cylindrical billboarding.

    decal.setRotation(look.nor(), axis); //Note that setRotation method requires 
        //direction vector to be normalized beforehand.
}
```

I didn't check to make sure the direction doesn't get flipped, because I draw it with back face culling turned off. So if you have culling on and don't see the sprite, that last cross product step might need to have its order reversed so the look vector points in the opposite direction.